# Trying to handle a Fortran pointer - call c_f_pointer

Tags: c, pointers, fortran, wrapper, fortran-iso-c-binding

I'm having a problem trying to handle a Fortran pointer after using:
`call c_f_pointer(dataPtr, dataF, [natoms,countf])`, where `dataPtr` is a C pointer with `intent(in)` and `dataF` is a Fortran pointer with `intent(out)`.

`natoms` and `countf` are integers to define the size of the output pointer.

Variables were previously declared as:

```
use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
integer natoms, countf
type(c_ptr) dataPtr
real(c_float), pointer :: dataF(:,:) => NULL()
```

and `dataPtr` comes from another function.

If I print `shape(dataF)` I get the correct result. But I cannot print or copy or do whatever with `dataF`. Error I get is *forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred*.

I followed the example https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/678433, which I can compile and manipulate with no problems.

---

EDIT: adding more of the code.

```
program test

use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
implicit none

interface
    subroutine open(ptr) bind(c, name='open')
        use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
        implicit none
        type(c_ptr), intent(out) :: ptr
    end subroutine open
    subroutine gather(ptr, name, typ, countf, data) bind(c, name='gather')
        use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
        implicit none
        type(c_ptr), value, intent(in) :: ptr
        type(c_ptr), value, intent(in) :: name
        integer(c_int), value, intent(in) :: typ
        integer(c_int), value, intent(in) :: countf
        type(c_ptr), intent(out) :: data
    end subroutine gather
    subroutine scatter(ptr, name, typ, countf, data) bind(c, name='scatter')
        use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
        implicit none
        type(c_ptr), value, intent(in) :: ptr
        type(c_ptr), value, intent(in) :: name
        integer(c_int), value, intent(in) :: typ
        integer(c_int), value, intent(in) :: countf
        type(c_ptr), intent(in) :: data
    end subroutine scatter
end interface

integer natoms, countf, typ
character(len=2,kind=c_char) :: var = c_char_'x'//c_null_char
type(c_ptr) ptr, dataPtr
real(c_float), pointer :: dataF(:,:) => NULL()

!opens an instance of the program (loaded as library into my Fortran)
!ptr is a pointer used to reference to it in other calls
call open(ptr)

!Here comes definitions for the integer variables
!...

!get data
call gather(ptr, c_loc(var), typ, countf, dataPtr)

!need to do stuff with the data here
call c_f_pointer(dataPtr, dataF, [natoms,countf])

!return modified data
call scatter(ptr, c_loc(var), typ, countf, dataPtr)
```

If I just get the data `call gather(...)` and then return it `call scatter(...)` the program works. But I need to do stuff in between.

---

EDIT2: added C functions

```c
void open(void **ptr) {
// ...
}

void gather(void *ptr, const char *name,
                     int type, int count, void *data) {
// ...
}

void scatter(void *ptr, const char *name,
                     int type, int count, void *data) {
// ...
}
```

Comment: If your C pointer is coming as an argument to your function called from C (that is, the dataPtr line is a dummy argument of your procedure) it also needs to be declared as `value`. Otherwise, the C-equivalent signature would be `double**`, not `double*`, as Fortran would be expecting a pointer _passed by reference_.

Comment: Please always show more code. See [mcve]. Do not try to describe the code by words, copy it here. It is very, very important.

Comment: Added more of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I got it.

First of all the data pointer has to enter as `intent(in)` and `value` in subroutine `gather`:

```
subroutine gather(ptr, name, typ, countf, data) bind(c, name='gather')
    ! ...
    type(c_ptr), value, intent(in) :: data
    ! instead of:
    ! type(c_ptr), intent(out) :: data
end subroutine gather
```

and i changed the declaration of `dataF`, which do not need to be called from `c_f_pointer` anymore:

```
real(c_float), target, allocatable :: dataF(:,:)
```

So I removed `call c_f_pointer(dataPtr, dataF, [natoms,countf])` and added instead:

```
allocate(dataF(natoms,countf))
dataPtr = c_loc(dataCFloat)
```

Now, `dataF` contains the updated array directly.